# A high school contest question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Compute the largest root of $$x^4 −x^3 −5x^2 +2x+6$$

I cannot solved it by factor,what else I may do.

Such a question, how to think.

Comment: What have you tried? When all else fails, grind it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Comment: If it is a contest question, grinding it out is not a good idea.

Comment: For a contest problem, I do not want to provide the approach either.

Comment: I don't think he is writing the contest as we speak.

Comment: Hint: the polynomial DOES factor over the rationals.

Comment: Maybe you have clairvoyant powers to know that, I do not.

Comment: How about just finding the roots of $f'$ , to see how $f$ changes?

Comment: @Amzoti You might be right, in which case we have failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $x^4-x^3-5x^2+2x+6=(x^4-5x^2+6)-x(x^2-2)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)-x(x^2-2)=(x^2-2)(x^2-x-3)$.

So we have two possible positive roots, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Notice that $\sqrt{13}>3$, so $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}>2>\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the largest root is $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$.

Comment: +1: What do you mean that we have two possible roots? I guess two positive roots, since your looking for the largest?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say two possible positive roots, I edited it. If you like my answer, please click as accepted :-)

Comment: no problem ; just nitpicking --it is a math website :). But I did not ask the question, so I don't have the option to accept, sorry.

Comment: I'm wondering what technique a high school student is supposed to employ to factor a biquadratic without rational roots.  I doubt they are teaching Decartes method.  Is it just assumed that all high school students are using calculators with that functionality nowadays?  This answer just says "epiphany" to me.

Comment: @DanielIV We are in fact taught this method in algebra 2 (in Texas, at least).